# Softlayer API for closing a session in golang?

Tags: session, go, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the softlayer go client 
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go

I am not able to close the softlayer session. How do I do that?

I have created the softlayer session using the `Session.New()` API. 
Reference:- https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/blob/master/session/session.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/blob/master/session/session.go 
 basically configures the go-client by storing the username, apiKey, endpoint, timeout, etc., in variables, which are used every time do a request to the API.

If you review the [SoftLayer API](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/softlayerapi/), it doesn't have any method that will create/close a session, so if you want to simulate something similar then I think you can try by sending blank values to `Session.New()` and removing any value stored in `~/.softlayer` file